# PHPStan and Doctrine: $id is never written, only read

Tags: php, doctrine, phpstan

I am using PHP8, symfony5 and doctrine2 with phpstan and getting these errors:

```
Property App\Entity\User::$id is never written, only read.
```

The code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    public const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';
    public const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVerified = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->audioSessions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The code is correct which is also acknowledged by PHPStan as described here: https://phpstan.org/blog/detecting-unused-private-properties-methods-constants#what-if-my-code-is-%E2%80%9Cspecial%E2%80%9D%3F

So how can i solve these error message in PHPStan?

I tried installing https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine and enabled this in my phpstan.neon file:

```
includes:
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/extension.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/rules.neon
```

But the error still persists.

Comment: Please show your Doctrine entity in question.

Comment: @OndřejMirtes i added the entitiy code.

Comment: This should work fine. Please create a small reproducing repository and submit this as an issue to https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine. Thanks.

Comment: Repository is created and issue is filed: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/issues/229

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure `objectManagerLoader` so that the extension can see the entity metadata.
This will allow DQL validation, and the correct entity `repositoryClass` to be inferred when accessing `$entityManager->getRepository()`. Add to your `phpstan.neon`:

```
parameters:
    doctrine:
        objectManagerLoader: tests/object-manager.php
```

Example for Symfony 5:

```
// tests/object-manager.php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(__DIR__ . '/../.env');

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$kernel->boot();
return $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

From the documentation:
https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine#configuration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works indeed :).

Comment: i accept the answer but it would probably be better if you copy the necessary parts from the docs to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am using phpstan ignore errors (https://phpstan.org/user-guide/ignoring-errors). To narrow the scope, my path is set to entity directory only.

```
# ./phpstan.neon

parameters:
    ignoreErrors:
        -
          message: '#Property [a-zA-Z0-9\\_]+::\$id is never written, only read.#'
          path: src/Entity/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/readonly_properties_v2) is implemented, PHPStan implemented this feature in the 1.4 version. Unforthunully, there is no @readonly attribute (at least for the moment) that can be used with PHP < 8. For more detail, feel free to see this [issue](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/4082).

Answer (score 0):

i've ignored this error by adding this lines to my *phpstan.dist.neon* file

```
    ignoreErrors:
    - '#Property .+::\$id is never written, only read\.#'
```